# Monitor Nestjs backend

Tags: server, devops

In the old days, when we wanted to monitor a "Daemon" / Service, we were asking the software editor the list of all the services running in the background in Windows.

If a "Daemon / service" would be down, it would be restarted.

On top of that, we would use a software like NAGIOS or Centreon to monitore this particular "Daemon / service".

I have a team of Software developper in charge of implementing a nice Nest JS.

Here is what we are going to implement:

> 2 differents VMs running on a high availability VMWARE cluster with a SAN
> the two VMs has Vmotion / High availabity settings
> an HA Proxy is setup in order to provide load balancing and additional high availability

Our questions are, how can we detect that :

> one of our backend is down ?
> one of our backend moving from 50ms average response time to 800ms ?
> one of our backend consumes more that 15Gb of ram  ?
> etc

When  we were using "old school" daemon, it was enough, when it comes to JS backend, I am a bit clue less.

Cheers

Kynes

nb : the datacenter in charge of our infrastructure is not "docker / kubernetes / ansible etc compliant)

Comment: That's not a programming question. It's off-topic for Stack Overflow. You could ask at [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, all of these seem doable out of the box for Centreon/Nagios. I'd say check the documentation...

> one of our backend is down ?

**VM DOWN:** the centreon-vmware plugins provides monitoring of VM status.

**VM UP but Backend DOWN :** use the native http/https url checks provided by Centreon/Nagios to load the web page.
Or use the native SNMP plugins to monitor the status of your node process.

> one of our backend moving from 50ms average response time to 800ms ?

**Ping Response time:** Use the native ping check

**Status of the network interfaces of the VM:** the centreon-vmware plugin has network interface checks for VMs.

**Page loading time:** use the native http/https url checks provided by Centreon/Nagios.

You may go even further and use a browser automation tool like selenium to run scenarios on your pages and monitor the time for each step.

> one of our backend consumes more that 15Gb of ram ?

**Total RAM consumed on server:** use the native SNMP memory checks from centreon/nagios.

**RAM consumed by a specific process:** possible through the native SNMP memory plugin.
Like so:

```
/usr/lib/centreon/plugins/centreon_linux_snmp.pl --plugin os::linux::snmp::plugin --mode processcount --hostname=127.0.0.1 --process-name="centengine" --memory --cpu
OK: Number of current processes running: 1 - Total memory usage: 8.56 MB - Average memory usage: 8.56 MB - Total CPU usage: 0.00 % | 'nbproc'=1;;;0; 'mem_total'=8978432B;;;0; 'mem_avg'=8978432.00B;;;0; 'cpu_total'=0.00%;;;0;`
```